# Difference between contrast enhancement options QGIS 3 rasterlayer symbology multiband color

Tags: qgis, symbology

When symbolizing a multiband color raster layer, in QGIS there is a field called contrast enhancement. In this field I have four options to choose from:
'no enhancement'  'Stretch to MinMax' 'Stretch an Clip to MinMax' 'Clip to MinMax'. What is contrast enhancement good for and what is the difference between the options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Stretching a raster image is a simple but effective visualisation technique which can help highlight features in an image.

If you consider an image in it's histogram form then it is most commonly observed with a Gaussian distribution. Now if you have the colour gradient running linearly from the Min and Max of the data set then you end up with a much shallower gradient. This means features often get lost in the image that share a relatively similar value. Now to get around this you can set your Min and Max values to remove "outliers" which gives you a larger colour gradient, thus features with relatively similar values stand out more.

For definitions I refer to Menke *et al*. (2016) which states the following:

> **No enhancement:** No enhancement is applied. The color gradient is
>   stretched across all values in the entire gray band. While this may be desired
>   sometimes, it may tend to make the raster look overly gray.
>
> **Stretch to MinMax:** This method stretches the color gradient across the
>   gray band between the Min and Max values. It generally produces a higher
>   contrast, a darker rendering than No enhancement. All cell values below the
>   Min value are assigned the lowest gradient color and all cell values above the
>   Max value are assigned the highest gradient color.
>
> **Stretch and clip to MinMax:** This method stretches the color gradient across
>   the gray band between the Min and Max values. It produces the same
>   rendering as the Stretch to MinMax method, except that all cell values below
>   the Min value and all values above the Max value are assigned no color (and
>   they are transparent).
>
> **Clip to MinMax:** This method stretches the color gradient across all values
>   in the gray band, which is the same result as No enhancement, except that
>   all cell values below the Min value and all values above the Max value are
>   assigned no color (and they are transparent).

**References**

Kurt Menke, G.I.S.P., Smith Jr, R., Pirelli, L. and John Van Hoesen, G.I.S.P., 2016. Mastering QGIS. Packt Publishing Ltd.